# Singleton and Interface implementation

Tags: c++, interface, singleton

I have an interface class `Interface` with pure virtual methods.

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
}
```

Also, there is a class `Implementation` that implements the interface.

```
class Implementation : public Interface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

In my program I need to have a Singleton (single instance) of `Implementation/Interface` pair. There are many pairs of `Implementation/Interface` classes in the program, but very few `Implementation` classes for one `Interface` class.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Should I invoke `Interface` or `Implementation` class from the rest of my program whenever I need to use the class? 
   How exactly should I do so?

   ```
    //Interface needs to know about Implementation
    Interface * module = Interface::Instance();

    //No enforcement of Interface
    Implementation * module = Implementation::Instance();

    //A programmer needs to remember Implementation and Interface names
    Interface * module = Implementation::Instance();

    //May be there is some better way
   ```
2. How should the method `Instance()` look like?

Comment: Don't use Singleton- problem solved.

Comment: There is just one instance of the class. The instance lasts for the duration of the program. It seems that singleton is OK in such a case.

Comment: No, it isn't. You're taking something that happens to hold true now and enforcing it for the entire lifetime of the codebase.

Comment: @Puppy, any better alternatives?

Comment: @Konstantin _"any better alternatives?"_ As mentioned, just pass the `Interface` references around with the rest of your code.

Comment: If there are never any other implementations of the interface, is it really even needed? Of course this will make it easier to add one if it is ever needed, but I wouldn't go making interfaces just because.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No you're wrong. It's the other way round. There's no need for a singleton. An interface enhances maintainability and robustness of code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't mean a singleton, I mean is there a reason to have an interface and an implemetation, when they could just have the implementation. Not regarding using singleton or not.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The OP's example is too simplified. Read their comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557133/singleton-and-interface-implementation/30557174?noredirect=1#comment49186721_30557174).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then I would vote editing the question, since it clearly says "There are ... not several Implementation classes for one Interface class." But this is a bit off-topic on this question, since it is only about the singleton.

Comment: @Konstantin ... continued: If a client needs a _bunch of interfaces_ as you're mentioning, you have the option to aggregate these to be passed to a client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"1) Should I invoke Interface or Implementation class from the rest of my program whenever I need to use the class? How exactly should I do so?"*

Use the interface, that will less clutter your code with `Implementation::Instance()` calls:

```
 Interface& module = Implementation::Instance();
       // ^
```

Note the reference, assignment and copy won't work.

> *"2) How should the method Instance() look like?"*

The common consensus is to use [Scott Meyer's approach](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf):

```
 Implementation& Instance() {
     static Implementation theInstance;
     return theInstance;
 }
```

---

The better alternative is not to use a singleton at all but make your code ready to operate on the `Interface` exclusively:

```
 class Interface {
      // ...
 };

 class Impl : public Interface {
      // ...
 };

 class Client {
     Interface& if_;
 public:
     Client(Interface& if__) : if_(if__) {}
      // ...
 }

 int main() {
     Impl impl;
     Client client(impl);
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What I don't get from it is how Implementation is related to Interface in terms of Instance() method.

Comment: `Implementation` inherits from `Interface` therefore an instance of `Implementation` _is-a_ instance of `Interface`.

Comment: How it works with `Interface& module = Interface::Instance();` then? `Implementation` has `Instance()`, `Interface` doesn't

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, fixed it in my answer.

Comment: `Interface& module = Implementation::Instance();` - in such a case I need to keep track of both `Interface` and `Implementation` in all parts of my program (and there are tens of such pairs). I'm wandering whether there is a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: @Konstantin Not you don't need to _keep track_. Just make sure you pass `Interface` references around. _"I'm wandering whether there is a more "elegant" solution."_ Well, the most elegant solution is not to use a Singleton at all, but just the interface and any kind of implementation for it, which may or may not include singleton instances.

Comment: _not to use a Singleton at all, but just the interface_ - could you please provide some example?

Comment: @Konstantin I wrote up a sample in my answer.

Comment: The problem with the sample is that every `Client` needs to have references to all interfaces it uses. And there are literally tens Interfaces and tens clients.

Comment: Well, singleton won't make the situation really better, but even worse from viewpoint of maintainability and robustness. `Client`'s should know, which interfaces they need.