# Problems with lazy initialization of singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

I want to make singleton class that has behavior like below.

1. My program has very limited resources, so I don't want to make singleton instance until I need it. (lazy initialization)
2. Singleton class is very huge so initialization takes very long time.
3. Response time is important in this program.(like games)

But as you know, 1 & 2 & 3 is conflict with each other.
In this conditions, I have to choose one of them (memory or performance)

Is there any solutions the program can meet memory & performance requirement?

Comment: The most straightforward answer seems to be: _DON'T USE SINGLETONS_ (unless you're a 100% sure what you're doing).

Comment: Do you require the singleton at some point in the program's execution, or is it possible that the program may not require its use for a given run? If it's the former, then you might as well initialise it at the start, since the memory and CPU will be a hit at some point, so I think the best place to hide it is at startup rather than halfway through execution of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Is there any solutions the program can meet memory & performance requirement?"*

These requirements will need to be satisfied regardless. To ensure *lazy instantiation* of a singleton class, I would recommend using scott meyer's singleton implementation to guarantee lazy/thread safe initialization as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30557174/1413395):

```
class Singleton {
public:
     static Singleton& Instance() {
          static Singleton theInstance;
          return theInstance;
     }
     delete Singleton(const Singleton&);
     delete Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);
private:
     Singleton() {}

};
```

About memory consumption you'll have to optimize it in different ways. I can't actually tell, where you might have potential to narrow your memory footprint. There's not enough information given with your question so far.

---

> *"But as you know, 1 & 2 & 3 is conflict with each other. In this conditions, I have to choose one of them (memory or performance)"*

I can't see any actual conflicts?? There might be a performance hit, at the first access to `Singleton::Instance`, but subsequent accessing won't trigger initialization, so what?

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to say as you don't give many details.Are your resources limited in memory and also disk? The singleton class takes time to initialize because it's huge, or because it has to do many calculations? How much is a long time? How much is huge? What's limited resources?

If you have disk space and if reading/writing disk is relatively fast, 
and if you can spend some time during initialization of your program, 
you could maybe create and serialize your class to disk (and keep the file
 locked) when starting up, and then read your instance from there when you need it if memory is scarce. Or create the singleton in another thread and do some other stuff in the main thread.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Read up upon _Singleton_, if you  even try answering such question here.

Comment: Is there any solutions the program can meet memory & performance requirement?

Comment: There's a number of options, that are actually handled orthogonally and unrelated from usage of a singleton or not.

Comment: "Is there any solutions the program can meet memory & performance requirement?" That's the actual question. In games, it is a law that you cannot get performance and optimized use of resources, you need a compromise, so these kinds of problems are really common. If using singletons or not is a good solution for this specific case, I can't tell.  You cannot say that you don't see no conflicts. The performance hit could be so bad that it fails certification of a game. Again, without knowing the specifics I cannot tell for sure, but this is something that all game developer teams suffer.

Comment: "There's a number of options, that are actually handled orthogonally and unrelated from usage of a singleton or not" Totally agree, that's why my answer is not specific to the use of a singleton. Even when not using a singleton, the problem of response time vs limited resources stand. But again, without knowing the details, it's really hard to say.

Comment: I've got no clue what you're trying to preach about. Initialization of a _Singleton_ would give a short performance hit, you'll have to bear anyways. Any further access would operate on already allocated resources. In other words, you're telling nonsense mostly.

Comment: *sigh* *sigh* Ok. I'm not trying to preach, but given the details in the question I would assume the problem is not just on how to create a singleton, but rather on memory vs. performance, that's why I asked for more specific details. I could give you an example, but it would be hard to do here as it would start an endless discussion. If you've programmed computer or console games and never had these kinds of problems, I congratulate you, but I can tell you that similar techniques as the one I described are common, (and devised by smarter people than me).