# how to declare a static variable inside an inline function?

Tags: c++

Can any one please let me know whether we can declare static variables inside an inline function and if we can how it is going to work between function calls.

Comment: You do it exactly the same way you do for non-inlined functions. Go give it a try. Don't worry, we'll wait.

Comment: See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30557174/1413395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and they should* behave exactly the same as for a non-inline static local.

* Visual Studio 6 (yes, that ancient compiler) has a bug where if the inline function gets both inlined and non-inlined in different translation units the local will get constructed twice.

Comment: Do people actually still care about compilers that are literally older than the language itself?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Evidently so. Also don't forget all 1.25 billion people in India are using a compiler that requires a DOS emulator to run....