# When does a constructor of a class with static members runs in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ so i don't know much about it yet
so basically i have this code
header file

```
class Application{
    public:
        static Application& getInstance()
        {
            return *mInstance;
        }
        Application();
        void run();
        protected:          
        static Application* mInstance;
```

source file

```
Application* Application::mInstance;
Application::Application()
    {
        mInstance = this;           
    }
```

then i do

```
 Application::getInstance().run();
```

When does the constructor for Application class runs?
It seems to work in visual studio.
So my question is why does this work?
Why does getInstance does not return a null pointer? since i have never instantiated the class.
Is this code standard?
will this work on any modern c++ compiler?

Comment: Do you create an object anywhere before getInstance?

Comment: When constructor runs, it is not "constructor of class", it is constructor of a specific object of that class. The code sample you posted so far does not create any objects of the class. So, the constructor never runs.

Comment: Better look into [Scott Meyer's singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557133/singleton-and-interface-implementation/30557174#30557174)

Comment: `Why does getInstance does not return a null pointer? since i have never instantiated the class.` Well, because UB. Your code is just plain wrong.

Comment: @deviantfan: No i don't create any object before calling getInstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of a class belongs to an **object**, i.e. if it is called **explicitly** by the code somewhere it creates an object in the memory (on the stack or on the heap). So if you do not call the constructor somewhere it is never executed.

I see only the point why this can run is that you did not specify the initial value of the `mInstance` pointer. This means that its value is undefined and accidentally can have some valid address. If the `run()` method does not touch the `mInstance` object itself your code can run ***sometimes* but *sometimes not***. This is the problem of uninitialized variables in C++.

But I suggest to follow the right singleton pattern:
1. Initialize `mInstance` as a `nullptr`.
2. The `getInstance()` function should call the constructor if `mInstance` is `nullptr`.

*(Just a general hint: Avoid passing `this` in constructor to somewhere else because at that point the object is not fully constructed and in case of multi-thread application it can cause issues.)*

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is executed whenever an object is constructed.

Static objects at file scope are constructed before calling `main()`.   However, if you are relying on order of construction of two such static objects (e.g. construction of one relies on the other already being constructed) you potentially have a problem.  The order of construction of statics defined in two distinct compilation units (aka source files) is unspecified.

Static objects that are local (e.g. to a function) are constructed as control passes through their declaration .... typically as their function is called for the first time.